# Is there any specific sbt version required to compile the cassandra-spark-connector

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I am assembling the "Cassandra-Spark-Connector". I just followed the steps below:

1. Git clone connector code
2. Run "sbt assembly"

During the assembly phase I am getting the following error:

```
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.11.2 -> 0.13.0
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources to /home/xxxxxx/Development/iAdLearning/spark-cassandra-connector/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[error] /home/xxxxxx/Development/iAdLearning/spark-cassandra-connector/project/Settings.scala:23: object Plugin is not a member of package sbtassembly
[error] import sbtassembly.Plugin._
[error]                    ^
[error] /home/xxxxxx/Development/iAdLearning/spark-cassandra-connector/project/Settings.scala:24: not found: object AssemblyKeys
[error] import AssemblyKeys._
[error]        ^
[error] /home/xxxxxx/Development/iAdLearning/spark-cassandra-connector/project/Settings.scala:217: not found: value assemblySettings
[error]   lazy val sbtAssemblySettings = assemblySettings ++ Seq(
[error]                                  ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I am running sbt 0.13.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the packaged sbt by running.

```
./sbt/sbt assembly
```

This will automatically download and use a valid version of sbt.

Answer (score 0):

Building Spark java connector requires sbt-assembly version 0.11.2 as defined in plugins.bat. It is likely you have a newer sbt-assembly version (ver. 0.13.0) installed in global plugins folder (~.sbt\0.13\plugins) which is causing this issue. 
Kindly rename the plugins folder in ~.sbt\0.13 and try to build it again.